# Aligning navigation items with logo in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to center navigation items with the image logo I have in the center of my navbar. as you can see in the image below the navigation links are positoned over my logo

[image]

And I'm trying to get it to look more like this:

[image]

Here is my nav code:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container text-xs-center">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href='{{ url("/") }}' class="nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Our Team</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Media</a>
                <a href='{{ url("/") }}' class="nav-item nav-link"><img src="./images/zipzap.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">About Us</a>
                <a href='{{ url("/contact") }}' class="nav-item nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                <a href='{{ url("/donate") }}' class="nav-item nav-link" id="donate">Support Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and the css:

```
a.nav-item{
    color:#000;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}

a.nav-item:hover{
    color:#000;
}

a.nav-item:active{
    color:#000;
}

.navbar-nav{
    display:inline-block;
}

#donate{
    background-color: #7ED321;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried something, Hope it work for you. https://jsfiddle.net/akoczv6c/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to align nav links with logo in bootstrap 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274486/trying-to-align-nav-links-with-logo-in-bootstrap-4)

Comment: it is, but no one answered that question

Comment: Someone has answered that question so you should probably close this duplicate question.