# trying to align nav links with logo in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having issues with aligning my navigation links with my logo. Currently, my logo is in the center of my navigation and the links for some reason are displaying above my logo rather than next to it. the image below shows my issue[image]

I am trying to get it to look like this:

[image]

here is my header code:

```
  <header id="header" role="banner">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <div class="container text-xs-center">
                        <div class="navbar-nav">
                            <a href='{{ url("/") }}' class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Home</a>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Our Team</a>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Media</a>
                            <a href='{{ url("/") }}' class="nav-item nav-link"><img src="./images/zipzap.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">About Us</a>
                            <a href='{{ url("/contact") }}' class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                            <a href='{{ url("/donate") }}' class="nav-item-link nav-item nav-link" id="donate">Support Us</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

and my css:

```
a.nav-item{
    color:#000;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px;
}

a.nav-item:hover{
    color:#000;
}

a.nav-item:hover{
    color:#000;
}

.navbar-nav{
    display:inline-block;
}

#donate{
    background-color: #7ED321;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#header{
    width:100%;
}

.header-inner{
    padding: 18px 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do

```
a.nav-item{
    color:#000;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:20px;
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

If that doesn't work, then try adding `line-height` property to get it to the desired vertical position.

Comment: Thanks! It works, but for some reason they green background around my support us button stretches. do you know if there is a way to do this that doesn't affect the background around that button?

Comment: If that worked can you please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks. As far as the green stretching, try defining a height for it.

Comment: The stretching is due to the padding you've suggested on the a link. I'd use line-height in this case so the stretching doesn't happen.